# client_max_body_size 0; is not being aplied even setting in every section

Tags: django, docker, nginx

Why `client_max_body_size 0;` is not being aplied??
I'm receiving the following error trying to upload a file of 50M.
`413 Request Entity Too Large nginx/1.25.3`.

But I have setted the `client_max_body_size 0;` in every section
My application is dockerized but mapping the config file to docker, so the config is working, but max body not

```bash
    client_max_body_size 0;
    
    upstream lito_upstream {
      # ip_hash;
      server viajah-api:8000;
      server front_viajah:3000;
    }
    
    server {
        client_max_body_size 0;
    
        location /static/ {
           client_max_body_size 0;
           autoindex on;
           alias /src/static/;
        }
    
        location /media/ {
           client_max_body_size 0;
           autoindex on;
           alias /src/media/;
        }
    
        location / {
            client_max_body_size 0;
            proxy_pass http://viajah-api:8000/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    
            # Passa os cabeçalhos de cookie
            proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
        }
    
        listen 8000;
      server_name api.viajahturismo.com.br;
    }
    
    #server
    server {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      #Defines the port on which the server will listen for requests.
      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      location /media/ {
          client_max_body_size 0;
          autoindex on;
          alias /app/media/;
      }
      location / {
          client_max_body_size 0;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_pass http://front_viajah:3000;
      }
    
    
      listen 3000;
      server_name viajahturismo.com.br;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of another container. I'm using nginx-proxy to do the reverse proxy, and it is in a different and global docker-compose.yml, the problem was because the nginx-proxy was overriding the nginx config. So I added a config file setting client_max_body_size 0 and mapped to the volume of the nginx-proxy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).